# Magento2 Module\Updater\Setup error

Tags: attributes, magento2, install-script

I'm trying install different modules on my magento2 (v.0.74).

But all of them generates the same error:

```
exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException'
with message 'Source class "\Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\Setup"
for "Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\SetupFactory" generation does not exist.'
in /var/www/m2.dev/www/m074/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Generator.php:179
```

I'm trying to find this class `\Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\Setup`, but it doesn't exist.

Modules which I tried to install:

> https://github.com/Marko-M/Magento2-Inchoo_SocialConnect
>
> https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/

I'm just trying to add any attribute anywhere. What are minimal steps for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those modules are not compatible anymore with the latest version of Magento 2.
There are no more install scripts in `sql` or `data` folders anymore.
In the latest versions there should be a `Setup/InstallSchema.php` file for install and a `Setup/InstallData.php` for data install.

You can give [this module](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule) a try, although I'm not sure this one works on the latest version either. I didn't have the time to test it.

Comment: thank you so much, I'l check it. Its very useful information!

Comment: thanks once again I have achieved addAttribute script. I'l post a solution in a few days in another question, which I created before.

Answer (score 0):

As Marius said, the recent versions use SPI classes for schema/data manipulations instead of schema and data scripts. We have recently updated our article to cover the actual flow of adding an attribute programmatically. You can check it out here:
http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/